# how to choose a password contains at least eight characters,Include numbers and letters,Sequence numbers are not,Do not repeat numbers

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I want to choose a password for the user to have at least 8 characters in the password he chooses, and also the number of letters, and that the duplicate numbers should not be sequential numbers when they want to write the password.

Comment: Sounds great! What have you tried?

Comment: "^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]{8,}$"
But I do not want to be sensitive,That is, if there were no big and small letters, there would be no problem either,And do not accept sequential and repetitive numbers at all

Comment: I think you'll need more than 1 regex to implement this correctly. Consider 1 regex per requirement. Also, sequence numbers and repeat numbers cannot be detected with regex alone.

Comment: What application language are you using?

Comment: What is your solution for duplicate numbers and sequences

Comment: I work with Swift

Comment: Oh good, you should be able to work something together in that language. I don't have an implementation for you but it would likely involve some looping constructs.  If you want more help on here, I highly suggest you do more research on your own first. Perhaps take some Swift tutorials if you don't know how to construct loops. Then, post some of your own code, explaining in detail what works and what in particular you need more help with. It's generally frowned upon to ask others to write code for you when you haven't shared any of your own.

Comment: Good luck to you

Answer (score 0):

This called `NSRegularExpression`, in the first you need to declare the regular expression string like this:

```
let langRexEx = "^[a-z.]+$"
```

Then create a function to check the string with the regular expression. For example just English chars and dot:

```
func verifyLanguage(value: String) -> Bool {

var returnValue = true

let langRexEx = "^[a-z.]+$" // just chars and dot

do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: langRexEx)
    let nsString = value as NSString
    let results = regex.matches(in: value, range: NSRange(location: 0, length:   nsString.length))

    if results.count == 0
    {
        returnValue = false
    }

} catch let error as NSError {
    print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    returnValue = false
}

return  returnValue
```

}

Important note: string of regular is hard to find.